# Is there a compiler define that separates Delphi 11.0 from 11.1?

Tags: delphi, delphi-11-alexandria

There are a few corrected issues in the VCL which had previous workarounds.  Is there some method to identify that Delphi 11.1 is in fact installed and not 11.0 so the fix can be used rather than the workaround? The compiler defines for `RTLVersion` and `CompilerVersion` have not changed and are still `35.0`. The static compiler define is also still `VER350`.

Comment: "*The compiler defines for RTLVersion and CompilerVersion have not changed and are still 35.0*" - if there have been changes in the RTL, `RTLVersion` should have been incremented. If it wasn't, Embarcadero would need to fix. But, if the changes are only in the VCL, then there is no `VCLVersion` constant that you can check for.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is `RTLVersion111` constant which you can use to determine whether you are dealing with 11.1

```
const
  RTLVersion111 = True;

{$IF RTLVersion111}
  Writeln('DEFINED RTL 11.1');
{$ELSE}
  Writeln('NOT DEFINED RTL 11.1');
{$IFEND}
```

Each Alexandria update additionally defines new appropriate `RTLVersion` constant so the Alexandria 11.3 will have all following constants defined:

```
const
  RTLVersion111 = True;
  RTLVersion112 = True;
  RTLVersion113 = True;
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `{$IF DECLARED(RTLVersion111)})` instead? Also, are older constants, like `RTLVersion1041` and `RTLVersion1041`, still being declared?

Comment: @RemyLebeau  It is a boolean constant so it can be used as-is. It is more readable this way. Older constants are not defined. For distinguishing major versions, one would use `RTLVersion` and then combining conditional compilation with `RTLVersion111` or other constants depending on particular code requirements.

Comment: <del>So the `RTLVersion111` constant is declared even in versions prior to Delphi 11.1, with the value `False`?</del> Ah, you rely on this property: ["If the identifiers referenced in the conditional expression do not exist, the conditional expression will be evaluated as False"](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/IF_directive_(Delphi)).

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand no, `RTLVersion111` is new in 11.1 (hence the 111 in its name).

Comment: WARNING! you can not rely on RTLVersion111 because it's not consistent across delphi version. For exemple in sydney 10.4.2 you have RTLVersion1041 and RTLVersion1042 defined but not in Alexandria :( same for RTLVersion that is 35.00 in all version of alexandria (11.0, 11.1 and 11.2)

Comment: @zeus hence Dalija's comment that you would have to first look at `RTLVersion`, and then look at `RTLVersionXXX` for specific major releases. For instance, if ` RTLVersion` indicates 10.4.x, only look at `RTLVersion104x`. If `RTLVersion` indicates 11.x, only look at `RTLVersion11x`. And so on.